# References on Gerbes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, gerbes

I am looking for some references related to gerbes and their differential geometry. Almost every article I have seen that is related to gerbes  there is a common reference that is Giraud's book Cohomologie non-abelienne. For me, it is not readable as I can not read french.

Only references I am familiar with are

- https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212266 Introduction to the language of stacks and gerbes
- https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106083 Differential Geometry of Gerbes
- https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611317 Notes on 1- and 2-gerbes

Out of these, only first article is more or less readable. The other two by Lawrence Breen are really not readable for me.

Some excerpt of comments answering such a request were

- "The standard reference is Giraud's book Cohomologie non-abelienne. This book is unreadable in the strongest possible meaning of the word *unreadable*."
- "I find most of the contemporary articles in this area, which are often nonsystematic in terminology and notation, plus wave hands and use jargon on most issues, much less readable than Giraud's book."
- "See Giraud's book on nonabelian cohomology."
- "I don't think telling someone to see a dense 470 page book in French on non-abelian cohomology is a helpful comment."

I am getting demotivated and irritated by lack of notes on gerbes and even in Mathoverflow there are not so much to see. Is this out of fashion now? Are there any one else who read/work on these? Iam not looking for something in Physics perspective.

Comment: This is certainly off topic on the main MO site.  You could ask it on meta.mathoverflow.net if you want (but I doubt that you will get a satisfying answer).

Comment: @NeilStrickland Sir, I am asking for current research trends and notes on gerbes. How is that off topic?

Comment: Whilst perhaps not the best written question, I personally share many of the same frustrations as the OP and would be interested in seeing some experts thoughts on good references for gerbes.

Comment: @cello If that is your actual question, then I suggest you remove all the earlier quotes and stats, which just give the impression that you are complaining about something, rather than asking about something

Comment: @YemonChoi I am just sharing my search. I believe it gives better idea of what is happening

Comment: @DanielLoughran please feel free to edit the question to make it better.

Comment: @cello I think this is a completely valid question. It would also help if you had a concrete problem or goal, as someone might know of a specific paper where this is addressed. I know a little bit about gerbes in algebraic geometry. For those you definitely don't need any $\infty$-categories. In any case, I think it would greatly help to be familiar with principal bundles and with stacks (for example at the level of Vistoli's notes on descent).

Comment: @YosemiteSam I do not have a long time goal or concrete problem as of now, I would ask my advisor tomorrow or the day after. Can you share your thought about gerbes in Algebriac geometry. I would like to hear about that as well. I am comfortable with Differential geometry of Principal bundles as in second chapter of Kobayashi and Nomizu and comfortable with Angelo Vistoli’s notes on descent minus material dealing with Algebriac geometry/quasi coherent sheaves in it.

Comment: There is a bunch of stuff in the Stacks project, even if it's not focussed as such.

Comment: @DavidRoberts can you be more specific?

Comment: Eg https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06QB but other places too

Comment: why is this on hold now?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik It is on hold, because 5 people voted to close, and 5 people have not voted to reopen.  I suggest you write the question you want to ask in the main text, and find a way to make it noticeable. Right now, I see a mess of quotes in a mix of bold and plain text, and it is easy to give up reading.

Comment: You should make some significant effort first to improve the layout of your post. It's currently unpleasant to read: it starts with "thanks" and copies of comments which are incomprehensible without context. Start writing a question first explaining what you're looking for, **avoid extensive use of boldface**, don't write a question that belongs on meta (as you did several times).

Comment: @S.Carnahan Is it better now? I do not know what more to change/delete. That bold letter was to emphasize what other users has written about that particular book.

Comment: @YCor In any case, thanks for making it look better. I delete all my comments in last half an hour as it does not really add any value now.

Comment: Can some one vote to reopen this question.

Comment: Don't forget the extensive work on _bundle gerbes,_ which is very geometric. It would help if you gave us some reasons why you are interested, or what you hope to do with your new-found knowledge.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I asked my advisor and he said I have to work on understanding about non abelian gerbes on orbifolds..

Comment: Mikhail Borovoi left the following comment on the Meta version of this question: If you are interested in nonabelian $H^2$ and related exact sequences, you might have a look at [Debremaeker's thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02128) and [my preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07366) (but I don't mention gerbes in my preprint).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book of Giraud is a fundamental reference on the subject, but you have to be used to the language of Grothendieck. A reference more accessible, for example for a differential geometer is the chapter 5 of the book of Brylinski which deals only with commutative gerbes.

J.L Brylinski  Loop Spaces, Characteristic Classes and Geometric Quantization.

Comment: YHank you, I knew this book but did not spend time on reading this. As you said, I will roughly go through chapter five and will respond..

Comment: To read Giraud's book, in addition to familiarity with the language of Grothendieck, you also need some familiarity with the language of France.

Comment: @bianchira I agree.

Answer (score 9):

My personal impression is that at least on the level of foundational theory, Higher Topos Theory of Lurie is a good source. I guess this also explain the hard time you feel finding references: Gerbes seat very naturally in the context of sheaves of spaces (in this language this is just a connected sheaf of 1-types!), and I guess that this language has not fully penetrated into standard algebraic geometry texts yet, or any subject which is not modern algebraic topology, actually. However, the situation do get better with time, and I think that gerbes will appear more in texts soon (in particular, they are not out of fashion, just sort of get revised by $\infty$-category theory). For example, I personally almost finished a paper with a whole section for gerbes-based obstruction theory in etale homotopy, so I know there's at least one text on the subject that will be on the archive soon :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I do not know if I can just start reading that book. I do not know what to respond for this. Looking forward for your paper.

Comment: A gerbe is a *connected* sheaf of 1-types (otherwise you get only a stack)

Comment: right, I forgot the connected thing, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Urs Schreiber has written a lot
on gerbes and their applications to physics:
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Urs+Schreiber

See, for instance, the expository works
“Differential cohomology in a cohesive ∞-topos”
and “Higher prequantum geometry”.
Most of his published papers (https://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Schreiber_U/0/1/0/all/0/1) use gerbes in some way.

Almost all of [Konrad Waldorf's papers](http://math.konradwaldorf.de/www/?show=papers&lg=en) also involve gerbes in some way,
and some of them may be more accessible to a beginner,
see, e.g., his survey with Christoph Schweigert [Gerbes and Lie Groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5467).

Comment: I have mentioned that I do not feel comfortable with “Physics”... can we not study gerbes just for their own sake?? Is it not interesting,?? What is your view on that?

Comment: @cello: Much of Urs Schreiber's work studies gerbes for their own sake.  As I said, gerbes *and* their applications to physics, not just applications of gerbes to physics.

Answer (score 4):

The following reference might be helpful for you:
[Hitchin, Lectures on Special Lagrangian submanifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9907034), $\S1$.

Comment: Yes, even my advisor said the same thing. +1.

Comment: I have read that first part. Is there any way I can ask you doubts separately (by email)? I have to explain so much here to ask a question and I am not sure if people here are ready to read very long question.